# EntityFramework Include and possibly join?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I have the following table structure as shown in the picture. (see: [Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXRbt.png)). Both tables ("Batches" and "Methods") reference to a "Project" table.
When I now create a new Project I would like to get all childs created as well.
Doing so I did the follwoing:

```
_dbContext.Projects.Where(x => x.Id == prjId)
            .Include(x => x.Batches)
            .Include(x => x.Batches.Select(y => y.Measurements))
            .Include(x => x.Methods).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();
```

Now the problem is the following:
New Batch and Method instances are created - thus they get a new ID(PK). The referenced Project_Id (FK) is set correct. But in my new Measurement instance only the Batch_Id(FK) is set correct and the Method_Id remains unchanged (has the old value) (see: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMXSn.png)).

What I need is that the Measurements.Mehtod_Id is set from the Methods table.
 Is there any suitable solution for that?

My entities look like the following

```
public class Project 
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Batch> Batches { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Method> Methods { get; set; }
}

public class Batch : BaseObject
{
    public Batch()
    {
        BatchFiles = new List<FileAttachment>();
        Measurements = new List<Measurement>();
    }
    public long Id { get; protected set; }
    public long Project_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Measurement> Measurements { get; set; }
}
public class Method : BaseObject
{
    public Method()
    {
        Parameters = new List<Parameter>();
    }

    public long Id { get; protected set; }
    public long Project_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Measurement> Measurements { get; set; }
}

public class Measurement 
{
    public int Id { get; protected set; }
    [ForeignKey("Batch")]
    public long? Batch_Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Batch Batch { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Method")]
    public long? Method_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Method Method { get; set; }
}

// creation code (just a copy with new IDs for all childs)
Project newProjectVersion = _dbContext.Projects.Where(x => x.Id == prjId)
            .Include(x => x.Batches)
            .Include(x => x.Batches.Select(y => y.Measurements))
            .Include(x => x.Methods)
            .AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();
_dbContext.Projects.Add(newProjectVersion);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You're showing the wrong code. It's the creation code that matters.

Comment: added the creation part as well as the basic structure of my entities

Comment: You must *also* include the `Methods` with the `Measurements`: `.Select(y => y.Measurements.Select(m => m.Method)))` and (this is important!) remove `AsNoTracking()` otherwise EF may build an object graph with duplicated `Method`s. The best approach is to get the data with one context (with proxy creation disabled) and `Add` them to another context.

Comment: @GertArnold Basically that's it. Why don't you turn your comment into an answer :)

Comment: No time right now. I like to explain a bit more :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that your `Select` statement doesn't connect `Measurement`s to `Method`s because of the `AsNoTracking()` addition. Only `Project`s and `Method`s are connected because they are explicitly `Included` off of the `Project` entity. The `Measurement`s have a `Method_id` but this is value is not accompanied by a `Method` in their `Method` property. You could check that in the debugger if you walk through the object graph (with lazy loading disabled though!). Because of this, when all entities will be `Add`-ed to the context, EF won't notice that measurements receive new methods.

You *could* get tempted to fix that by `Include`-ing `Measurement.Method` as well:

```
...
.Include(x => x.Batches.Select(y => y.Measurements.Select(m => m.Method)))
...
```

Now you'll see that `Measurement.Method` will be populated everywhere in the object graph.

However, there's a gotcha here. When using `AsNoTracking`, EF6 doesn't keep track of entities it materialized (duh). This means that for each `Measurement` it creates a new `Method` instance, even if an identical `Method` (by id) was materialized before for another `Measurement`. (And in this case it will always materialize duplicates, because you already include `Project.Methods`.)

That's why you can't do this in the quick way with `AsNoTracking` and `Add` using one context instance. You'll get an error that EF tries to attach duplicate entities.

You must build the object graph using one context, with tracking, so EF will not materialize duplicates. Then you must `Add` this object graph to a new context. Which will look like this:

```
Project project;

using(var db = new MyContext())
{
    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    project = db.Projects.Where(x => x.Id == prjId)
                .Include(x => x.Batches)
                .Include(x => x.Batches.Select(y => y.Measurements))
                .Include(x => x.Methods).FirstOrDefault();
}

using(var db = new MyContext())
{
    db.Projects.Add(project);
    db.SaveChages();
}
```

Three remarks:

- Proxy creation is disabled, because you can't attach a proxy to another context without explicitly detaching it first.
- No, I didn't forget to include `Measurement.Method`. All methods are loaded by including them in the `Project` and now (because of tracking, and assuming that measurement will only have methods of the project they belong to), EF connects them with the `Measurement`s by *relationship fixup*.
- EF-core is smarter here: when adding `AsNoTracking` it won't track materialized entities, but still, it won't create duplicates either. It seems to have some temporary tracking during the construction of an object graph.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer so far. This works quite fine right now. Unfortunately I noticed that the Measurements entity has another required relationship to a table named 'MeasurementTypes':

```
[Required]
public virtual MeasurementType MeasurementType { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("MeasurementType")]
public long MeasurementType_Id { get; set; }
```

In contrast to Batches and Methods these entries must not be copied and the entries already exist in the MeasrementTypes table.
What would be a good way to put the required reference to the Measurements?

Comment: That means that they should keep the `MeasurementType_Id` they already have, i.e. you don't have to change anything (and certainly not include `MeasurementType`).

Comment: By the way. This should have been a comment below my answer or an edit to your question. Stack Overflow is pretty strict in what's an answer and what isn't.

Comment: Ok - noted @comments and answers.
Thanks for your help!